# Errors when using $postName = $_POST[variable]

Tags: php, post

When I try to run this code, I get the following error: undefined offset. I hope this is enough code to explain myself.

```
$images_id = $row["image_id"];
echo "
    <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"$images_id\" value=\"like\" />
    </form>
";
$postName = $_POST["$images_id"];
```

Comment: First, do a `print_r($_POST);` and make sure the value exists in your `$_POST` array. Second, remove the double quotes from your `$postName` declaration. Do `$_POST[$images_id];` instead (after making sure `$images_id` contains what you want).

Answer (score 1):

If your form isn't being posted back, there is no data available in `$_POST`. You need to check for the existence of your key within the array, before you try to access it:

```
if (array_key_exists($images_id, $_POST)) {
  $postName = $_POST[$images_id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake for new PHP users. Do yourself a favor and create a function that handles the tedious process of checking variables:

```
<?php
function getPostValue($key, $default = false)
{
    if ( isset($_POST[$key]) ) {
        return $_POST[$key];
    }
    return $default;
}
?>
```

This approach is used by many popular PHP frameworks such as Laravel, Codeigniter, etc.